# JS Подсветка активного пункта меню и тех что уже проскролили

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Здравствуйте уважаемое комьюнити. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать чтобы при скролле активный пункт меню подсвечивался, а те пункты что пользователь уже проскролил оставались активным. При этом если пользователь возвращается назад и проходит секции которые уже были активны, у пункта меню убирался активный класс. Как такое можно реализовать?

Пока я смог только сделать добавление класса active (иными словами подсветку) у активного пункта меню.

```js
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
           var $sections = $('section');
   $sections.each(function(i,el){
          var top  = $(el).offset().top-100;
          var bottom = top +$(el).height();
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
          var id = $(el).attr('id');
       if( scroll > top && scroll < bottom){
              $('a.active').removeClass('active');
                  // $('.div.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.div[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
     $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active');

          }
      })
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="menu">
   <a href="#contacts">контакти</a>
   <a href="#eight">бронювати</a>
   <a href="#seven">Alterra Group </a>
   <a href="#five">3D тур</a>
   <a href="#four">тех. хар.</a>
   <a href="#three">місія</a>
   <a href="#two">Комфорт</a>
   <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
    
     <div class="first" id="first">two</div>
      <div class="first" id="first">two</div>
      <div class="first" id="first">two</div>
      <div class="first" id="first">two</div>
```

Comment: для начала напишите, что в вашем понимании означает "становиться активным при скролле". Пункт считается активным когда появляется снизу? Когда достигает середины экрана? когда добирается до верха страницы?

Comment: Когда добирается до верха страницы

Answer (score 0):

Тогда схема такая:

На `onScroll` нужного блока вешается функция, которая:

1. отслеживает положение ВСЕХ пунктов меню (в цикле) И
2. если положение верха пункта меню  равно или меньше положения верха скроллируемого блока, то добавляет пункту меню класс типа `active` И
3. если положение верха пункта меню  больше положения верха скроллируемого блока, то убирает у пункта меню этот класс.

Но тут проблема в том, что вы не увидите, остались ли активными предыдущие пункты меню, или нет, ибо они будут скрыты за границей скроллируемого блока. Если вас это устраивает, то всё. Если нет, то недостаточно условий и  надо сделать немного предположений.

Если предположить, что пункт меню становится неактивным, когда добирается до низа страницы (вернее, скроллируемого блока или окна браузера), то пункт 3 в вышеприведенном алгоритме будет такой:

3. если положение НИЗА пункта меню  больше или равно положению НИЗА скроллируемого блока / страницы / окна браузера, то убирает у пункта меню этот класс.

Пробуйте.